# Bourne Shell Script Search for String

Tags: string, shell, grep, sh

Having trouble in bourne getting script to find a a matching string in a text file from user input. No luck searching online, the grep line just does not seem to want to work for me, ive tried multiple different variations with quotes etc. Any advice as to how i can get this to work? Cheers!

```
file="/home/Jonnonield/kit104agn2/teledir.txt"

echo "Enter name or number to search directory:"
read nameNumber

if grep -q $namenumber "$file"  ; then
    echo "string found"
else
    echo "not found"
fi
```

Comment: You're reading variable `nameNumber` and then grepping with completely different variable `namenumber` (no captial N in the middle). If you want more help, edit your question to include some sample input and expected output.

Comment: And get rid of the `-q` option to grep when debugging.

Comment: oh god i am an idiot thankyou for pointing out my stupidness

Comment: Also, it's extremely unlikely that you're using the 40 year old Bourne shell. It's far more likely that you're using one of its modern successors (Bash being the most popular). There are differences between the various shells that can be important when writing shell scripts.

Answer (score 0):

You're reading variable `nameNumber` and then grepping with completely different variable `namenumber` (no captial N in the middle). – Ed Morton

Comment: You should probably vote to close as a simple typo instead of posting an answer (though good call on making it a community answer!)